# How can I align a bunch of layers in Photoshop CS3 to a curve?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, alignment

Is it possible to take a series of layers (say, icons of seats in a theatre) and align/distribute them all to a curve (so they appear as a row)?

What I'm looking for is similar to "align text to path".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really hope there's an easier way in photoshop. If I had to do it in photoshop here's how I would do it:

1. Draw a reference curve
2. Place your seats along the curve
3. When done, align with: `Distribute Horizontal Centers`
4. Add guides and vertically align the seat with the "matching" one
5. Now you can duplicate this row, for more rows

[image]

Not the most elegant solution, and it requires some work. I really hope someone comes up with a better answer for Photoshop.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea Photoshop had added Align and Distribute! I was just looking for that this weekend. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure when it was added, I do hope support for it exists in CS3 as well.

Comment: yes, it's in CS3.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the best way to do it.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above processes are little bit difficult; you can achieve this type of aligning using brush pallet and stroke path.

1. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to get brush pallet
2. Choose brush tip shape tab
3. Change the spacing value according to your need
4. Draw your path or symbol right click
5. Select store path choose brush and press okay

Answer (score 0):

The example you give sounds like one for Illustrator instead, using 'Blend along a path' or possibly a pattern brush.